# Prolog - How to make a circular permutation

Tags: prolog

I am new to Prolog and I want to find out how can I make a predicate that behaves as follows:

```
?- circle([1,2,3],X).
X = [1,2,3];
X = [2,3,1];
X = [3,1,2];
false.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? SO(StackOverflow) will not give anyone a ready made solution.

Comment: @Dan: The notion circular permutation does not seem to fit. Or does it?

Comment: @false I think this is called a "rotation". So... in a very oblique way it might.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`append/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3) twice:

```
circle(L, C):-
  append(Head, [First|Tail], L),
  append([First|Tail], Head, C).
```

Comment: No need in `First` and `Tail`. Also `Head` is misleading as it is a list rather than element.

Comment: Very nice answer. @EugeneSh.: these [First|Tail] **are** necessary to avoid empty lists to come into play, with related duplicates.

Comment: @lurker: note that [First|Tail] avoids matching the empty list... and then avoid the duplicate. Gusbro coded it correctly

Comment: @CapelliC yes, true. I didn't read your response to EugeneSh very carefully!